# Exposure value changes but image brightness remains same (Nikon D5600, Manual Mode)

Tags: nikon, exposure, nikon-d5600

I have Nikon D5600. I have tried several times in Manual mode to change the ***exposure value by pressing the exposure button*** (given in the top control) and rotating the dial. I can see that the exposure value changes (plus or minus) but once I click the photo, the brightness of the photos remain same (although if you check the details, the exposure value is equal to the value that I set).

On the other hand, if I change the ***exposure value by pressing the info `i` button and then change the value using touch screen*** then, the brightness of the photos changes as per the set values.

Why brightness/exposure remains same (even the values show in data differ)  if you change exposure settings using `+/-` dedicated button?

Comment: Unless the 5600 is very different to the 5500, Exposure Compensation doesn't work in Manual Mode; it adjusts Aperture instead; though I think that might be a setting... which I can't track down in the manual right now :/ If it does 'work' then it is for metering only.

Comment: Do you have  ISO set to 'Auto' while using 'Manual' exposure mode?

Comment: @Tetsujin: I also thought that the exposure cannot be changed in Manual mode but then, why do it changes if I change it by pressing `i` and using touchscreen? Secondly, if its not changing during manual mode then, why the details of a photo shows different Exposure values? I will post some sample pictures in few hours to bring more clarity.

Comment: @MichaelClark: No, the ISO is also in Manual and I can change its value using the dial+Fn.

Comment: I'm not seeing what you're seeing. If I set to manual, the wheel is shutter speed, hold Fn it's ISO, hold +/- it's aperture. If I point at a known light source & set exposure correctly to the meter, then shift exp comp in *i* & re-check the same light source, the meter shows differently... but the compensation itself must be done manually to re-centre the meter.

Comment: @Tetsujin: By holding +/- and rotating the dial (and in Manual mode), doesn't the exposure value (just the written displayed value, not the actual exposure value) changes in your case?? Keep pointing the camera to the same object.

Comment: pressing +/- & turning the dial I see Aperture change, nothing else. Same in the viewfinder & on the rear main screen. As a result, the exposure over/under meter changes - but that's not the result of Exp Comp. I can take the aperture up a stop & then the exp comp down a stop & see the same metering; of course that picture would be a stop "wrong" because it's then compensated. I could achieve exactly the same result changing either ISO, exposure or aperture & just meter 1 stop away from centre.

Comment: @skm It seems you are conflating *Aperture value* (the f-number) and *Exposure value* (the EV number). They're two different things. You need to post photos of what you are talking about so we can see what you seem to be mistaking for something else.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that Nikon, but usually in manual mode the exposure meter is "display only", showing the exposure you get with the current parameters.

For the exposure to actually be an input, you would need to be on one of the "less manual" settings, where the camera is responsible for computing some of the values. For canons that would be Av/Tv, where you set the aperture and the camera finds the exposition time to achieve that exposure; or you set the exposition time and the camera sets the aperture.

Comment: I also thought that the exposure cannot be changed in Manual mode but then, why do it changes if I change it by pressing `i` and using touchscreen? Secondly, if its not changing during manual mode then, why the details of a photo shows the set Exposure values (without actually showing any change in the brightness)?

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact expected. Manual mode changes the exposure by adjusting exposure parameters: Shutter-Speed, Aperture and ISO.

Exposure-Compensation is for adjusting an automatically metered exposure, so has no effect in manual mode. The meter you see is actually an indication of how far off the camera considers the set exposure compared to the metered one. When you adjust EC (+/-) you are adding a bias from to the metered exposure so that what is shown is the difference between the metered exposure +/- the dialed-in EC compared to the manually chosen exposure.

Comment: Very nice answer, think it would be even better if it also addresses auto-iso, which is also available in "manual" mode, due to historic reasons.

Answer (score 0):

the +/- button on the top of the camera, by the shutter button, changes the aperture when in manual mode. If you haven't changed the iso off of auto, the iso will change when you change when you change the aperture.